# Sendmail through smarthost on non-standard port

Tags: sendmail

I'm trying to get my sendmail server to send mail through GoDaddy as a smarthost.  I confirmed that I can telnet to smtpout.secureserver.net on port 3535 and their SMTP responds properly.  But my sendmail service just can't get mail out - and I can't understand why.  I've configured the smarthost portion of sendmail as follows:

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtpout.secureserver.net')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER',`esmtp')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 3535')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash /data/smtp/client-info')dnl
```

The maillog shows (at loglevel 99):

```
Feb 26 12:03:56 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: SMTP outgoing connect on [172.31.234.15]
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: AUTH=client, relay=smtpout.secureserver.net., mech=LOGIN, bits=0
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: to=<validuser@mydomain.com>, ctladdr=<root@myhost.mydomain.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120448, relay=smtpout.secureserver.net. [173.201.192.229], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: dropenvelope, e_flags=0x4605862, OpMode=q, pid=4694
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: alias <root@myhost.mydomain.com> => support@mydomain.com
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: assigned id
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: v1QH3vXi004694: DSN: Service unavailable
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: queueup ./qfv1QH3vXi004694
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: sendenvelope, flags=0x604082
Feb 26 12:03:57 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: SMTP outgoing connect on [172.31.234.15]
Feb 26 12:03:58 myhost sendmail[4694]: AUTH=client, relay=smtpout.secureserver.net., mech=LOGIN, bits=0
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: to=support@mydomain.com, delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=31662, relay=smtpout.secureserver.net. [173.201.193.101], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: dropenvelope, e_flags=0x46050a2, OpMode=q, pid=4694
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: alias MAILER-DAEMON => postmaster
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: alias postmaster => root
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: alias root => support@mydomain.com
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: alias postmaster => root
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: alias root => support@mydomain.com
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: assigned id
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: v1QH3vXj004694: return to sender: Service unavailable
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: queueup ./qfv1QH3vXj004694
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: sendenvelope, flags=0x604082
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: SMTP outgoing connect on [172.31.234.15]
Feb 26 12:03:59 myhost sendmail[4694]: AUTH=client, relay=smtpout.secureserver.net., mech=LOGIN, bits=0
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: to=support@mydomain.com, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=32686, relay=smtpout.secureserver.net. [173.201.193.101], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: dropenvelope, e_flags=0x46050a2, OpMode=q, pid=4694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: alias MAILER-DAEMON => postmaster
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: alias postmaster => root
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: alias root => support@mydomain.com
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: unlink ./dfv1QH3vXj004694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: unlink ./qfv1QH3vXj004694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: done; delay=00:00:01, ntries=1
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: unlock
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: unlink ./xfv1QH3vXj004694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXj004694: ./xfv1QH3vXj004694: unlink-fail 2
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: NOQUEUE: dropenvelope, e_flags=0x4050a2, OpMode=q, pid=4694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: Losing ./qfv1QH3vXi004694: savemail panic
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: SYSERR(root): savemail: cannot save rejected email anywhere
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: unlink ./qfv1QH3vXi004694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: ./qfv1QH3vXi004694: unlink-fail 2
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: done; delay=00:00:03, ntries=1
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: unlock
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: unlink ./xfv1QH3vXi004694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3vXi004694: ./xfv1QH3vXi004694: unlink-fail 2
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: NOQUEUE: dropenvelope, e_flags=0x4050a2, OpMode=q, pid=4694
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: unlink ./dfv1QH3uXi004692
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: unlink ./qfv1QH3uXi004692
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: done; delay=00:00:04, ntries=1
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: unlock
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: unlink ./xfv1QH3uXi004692
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: v1QH3uXi004692: ./xfv1QH3uXi004692: unlink-fail 2
Feb 26 12:04:00 myhost sendmail[4694]: NOQUEUE: dropenvelope, e_flags=0x407062, OpMode=q, pid=4694
```

I *assume* this is related to the connection since I see no other errors in the log.  If this is credential related I can post more info.

Can someone explain why this is failing?

Comment: Doesn't explain why it's failing, but I suppose you could always set up a local TCP port mangling in iptables and shove traffic to `127.255.0.1:25` (or something equally unused) in the direction of smtpout.secureserver.net:3535...

Comment: Use debug procedure sescribed at http://serverfault.com/a/521614/163277 . Trace map lookups (authinfo lookups).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sendmail leaves NO clues when the problem is on the receiving side.  Previously I tested the SMTP connection using telnet, but didn't think I could send a full email (via telnet) because authentication was required.  I found [this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/sendmail-relay-to-godaddy-788580/) which shows how to construct the auth command and then test email.

It turns out the receiving SMTP server was rejecting the mail because the domain name on the FROM line did not have a DNS entry.  After fixing that, the mail went through on telnet, and subsequently went through on sendmail.